# Oracle Transaction - Count table

Tags: oracle, concurrency, transactions

I have a table where I need to constrain by category and then find all overlapping dates against some date range.  This takes about 2 seconds, which is unacceptable to do on every transaction which occurs at roughly 50/s.  The alternative is to create some tally table -- then again, I don't know how great of an idea this is because things can get out of sync.

```
Date on Rent   # Rented   Category
9/5/2011       5          CATEGORY1
```

In Oracle (PL/SQL, if it matters), how can I maintain this performance, but ensure that concurrent transactions don't screw up the increment / decrement by making it one less or one more than it really is?

I have two types of transactions, kind of like a search and a rent.  Only rents will be updating this tally table (and searches just reading from it).  I don't mind if rents slow down, but do not want search performance impacted.  Rents can occur as frequently as 5-10 / second.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused: what do you really want?  Have you really exhausted tactics for improving the original query?  What have you tried so far?  What version of the database?  Which edition?  What's the data like: total rows in table, number of categories, breadth of date range?

Comment: Date range can be up to 6 months.  Most dates are probably for 5 days, as there is a late fee.  I use 10gR2.  Total rows are around 12 million.  I can get the query down to 1.7 seconds when I remove some constraints (of which I know cause problems and can be worked around), but that's still too slow.  I'd need it to be like 0.02 seconds.  The constraint to find overlapping dates is something like `AND to_date('07/05/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') <= return_date AND to_date('07/18/2011 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= start_date`.

Comment: Note that most of those rows are historical and only the present and future rows need to be looked at.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses locks to ensure data consistency during a query. The details of how they work can get complex, but the effect is that it guarantees that an update/insert to your tally table will only use the data in the main table as it was when the query began. If there is another update or insert to your main table while you are doing an update/insert to the tally table, it won't affect it.

You'll have to experiment with your data to see if keeping a summary/tally table helps or hurts you. It really depends on how quickly the main table is getting updated, how much time you spend updating your tally table vs how much time you save by being able to select on it, and how up-to-date you need selects to be.

Comment: Oracle does not use locks to guarantee read consistency: it uses data from the UNDO tablespace to present a consistent result set.  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#i5702